# One to Many Relationship Query with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, i am working on an application with firebase realtime database. In database, they are Customer and Work objects. The structure of my present data is illustrated below. I want to filter to works  by customer. What kind of query do I have to do in the firebase?

```
+--customers
  |
  +-- customerKey1
  |  |
  |  +-- <customerData1> ..
  |  
  +-- customerKey2
     |
     +-- <customerData2>..

+--works
  |
  +-- workKey1
  |  |
  |  +-- customerKey : customerKey2  // this work belongs to customer2
  |  |
  |  +-- <the rest of work1 data
  |  
  +-- workKey2
  |  |
  |  +-- customerKey : customerKey2  // this work belongs to customer2
  |  |
  |  +-- <the rest of work2 data
  |  
  +-- workKey3
  |  |
  |  +-- customerKey : customerKey1  // this work belongs to customer1
  |  |
  |  +-- <the rest of work3 data
  |  
  +-- workKey4
     |
     +-- customerKey : customerKey1  // this work belongs to customer1
     |
     +-- <the rest of work4 data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `works` nodes for a specific customer you use a Firebase query:

```
firebase.database().ref('works').orderBy('customerKey').equalTo('customerKey2')
```

For more on this, see the [Firebase documentation on sorting and filtering lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: If I take both lists in the backend and filter them according to each other, do I experience performance loss?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what that means. You might want to give it a try and post your results if they're not fast enough.

Comment: Ah.... I just realize what you may mean. If you're asking whether doing a client-side join of the data for each customer is going to be too slow, it typically isn't because the Firebase Database client can pipeline these requests. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786